# Why do websites like Truecaller make you prove that you are not a robot after a limited number of searches?

Tags: attacks, ddos, websites, captcha

I used Truecaller for searching for a number but after around 20 to 25 searches they started asking me to prove that I am not a robot. Is this for protecting their website from a DDoS attacks or is it a normal security precaution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably partly to limit load on the servers, be it from a malicious DoS attacks or just someone who makes loads of requests for legit reasons.

Another big reason is to stop people from scraping all the data from the site (telephone numbers and their owners in this case). Or think of it like this: If they did not have this kind of protection, I could set up my own websites offering the exact same service as Truecaller does. All my server would need to do would be to call Truecaller and pass on the informaiton to my customer. Only I will be displaying my own ads, not theirs, effectively "stealing" their ad revenue.